# jQuery click event not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm testing out some layout coding in jsfiddle before implementing it on the site I'm working on. Not sure if this is a jsfiddle specific question, but the click event on the triangle doesn't seem to be working.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/velocirabbit/0qaam2vh/)

```
    var $MenuTriangle = $(".menu.triangle");
    $MenuTriangle.click(function () {
    alert("click handler called");
    if ($(this).css("transform") == 'none') {
        $(this).css("transform", "rotate(90deg) translate(1px,1.5px)");
        $(this).css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(90deg) translate(1px,1.5px)");
        $(this).css("-moz-transform", "rotate(90deg) translate(1px,1.5px)");
        $(this).css("-ms-transform", "rotate(90deg) translate(1px,1.5px)");
        $(this).css("-o-transform", "rotate(90deg) translate(1px,1.5px)");
    } else {
        $(this).css("transform", "");
        $(this).css("-webkit-transform", "");
        $(this).css("-moz-transform", "");
        $(this).css("-ms-transform", "");
        $(this).css("-o-transform", "");
    });
```

It seems like pretty typical stuff, so I'm not sure what the issue is. I'm pretty sure jsfiddle adds the $(document).ready(....) for you, but in either case, the code doesn't even work when I add it myself, so I don't think that's the issue.

Can anyone spot what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: You just miss a } to close the else at the end. Last line should be }});

Comment: Check the Javascript console, it complains of a syntax error. And jsfiddle only adds the `$(document).ready()` if you select `onDomReady` from the menu. It defaults to `window.onload`.

Comment: Ugh, I'm so dumb. That's probably what I get for testing in jsfiddle and not a real IDE. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing `}` that should be on the second last line of your code — in other words, you forgot to close the `else {...` condition. It is fixed now: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/0qaam2vh/8/

In addition, jQuery automatically adds vendor prefixes, so you can actually simplify your code into the following:

```
var $MenuTriangle = $(".menu.triangle");
$MenuTriangle.click(function () {
    alert("click handler called");
    if ($(this).css("transform") == 'none') {
        $(this).css("transform", "rotate(90deg) translate(1px,1.5px)");
    } else {
        $(this).css("transform", "");
    }
});
```

In fact, I would recommend toggling a class instead of using the `.css()` function ;)

Comment: On the downvote: If someone would leave a comment on why the answer is not satisfactory, I'm all ears.

Comment: Ugh, I'm so dumb. That's probably what I get for testing in jsfiddle and not a real IDE. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, if you run into issues the first thing you should try is to validate your JS first :) http://www.jshint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check the javascript console (depending on your OS/device, usually F12 or "Developer tools" or similar from the browser): you are missing a curly brace at the end of the `click` handler function definition.

Fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vtLkzwg7/

```
var $MenuTriangle = $(".menu.triangle");
$MenuTriangle.click(function () {
alert("click handler called");
if ($(this).css("transform") == 'none') {
    $(this).css("transform", "rotate(90deg) translate(1px,1.5px)");
    $(this).css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(90deg) translate(1px,1.5px)");
    $(this).css("-moz-transform", "rotate(90deg) translate(1px,1.5px)");
    $(this).css("-ms-transform", "rotate(90deg) translate(1px,1.5px)");
    $(this).css("-o-transform", "rotate(90deg) translate(1px,1.5px)");
} else {
    $(this).css("transform", "");
    $(this).css("-webkit-transform", "");
    $(this).css("-moz-transform", "");
    $(this).css("-ms-transform", "");
    $(this).css("-o-transform", "");
}}); // <== fixed this line
```

Comment: Ugh, I'm so dumb. That's probably what I get for testing in jsfiddle and not a real IDE. Thanks!